# How to iterate over List<List<String>> which is returned by Apex, in a flow?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I am invoking an apex class in my flow, which returns List<List< String>> back to the main flow. The flow surprisingly doesn't let me store the returned value in a collection variable. Now I want to loop over the inner list of strings and display each value from the list as a line item on a screen, however, I do not have a collection variable to loop over. Please see the attached screenshots. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like you may be having an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why are you returning a `List<List<String>>` in the first place?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Because InvocableMethods are bulkified, thus to return a collection, you need a list of list of some type.

Answer (score 3):

You've chosen the wrong combination of settings in your Apex Action element. You must either (a) create a new Collection from the Resource Manager, check the *Manually assign variables*, and then assign that Collection in the box below (that reads *output* in your first screen shot), or (b) uncheck the *Manually assign variables* checkbox, which will provide you with an automatically created collection called *Text Collection from <Apex Action Name>*. By using the *Manually assign variables* checkbox and leaving *output* blank, you're effectively discarding the results of the call.

When you uncheck *Manually Assign Variables*, you get the following Collection automatically:

[image: Automatic Collection]

You can then use this directly in a loop:

[image]

---

When you check the box, you must create your own:

[image: Create New Resource]

---

[image: Assigning Output]

---

[image: Using in a Loop]